# Using js verification to change background-image

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm with a little problem. I was building a form in HTML with javascript, but in the inputs, i've used a background-image and a padding in left to make it look better, here its all ok, the problem comes next. I've created this function here:

```
function verificar_email(email) {
var valor = email.value;

if (valor.length != 0){
    if (valor.indexOf('@') >= 1) {
        if (valor.indexOf('.') > (valor.indexOf('@') + 1)) {
            if (valor.length > (valor.lastIndexOf('.') + 1)) {

                email.style.background = "#1abc9c";
                email.style.color = "#fefefe";
                return true;

            }
        }
    }
}
email.style.background = "#ff0000";
email.style.color = "#fefefe";
return false;
}
```

When the email input is blank or typed wrong, it's filling my bgimage with bgcolor and making the image dissapear. How can i change my original image to other image i've created without filling with color?

Sorry for my bad english, below i will explain what i'm talking about with some images.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VWKj.jpg - the first image is the error, the second is what it looks like and the final image is what i wanna do.

Comment: Why are you using images in the first place?

Comment: Just don't use `background` but only `backgroundColor` (or `backgroundImage` if you want to change that)

Comment: Sharf: " i've used a background-image and a padding in left to make it look better"

Bergi: Thanks for it, but its not changing the original bgimage.

Comment: I'm with Sharf, there is absolutely nothing you're doing there that needs images.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/A6Csy/1 << No images, does what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply set the background color to "transparent" which should stop your background image disappearing

Comment: Thanks Chris, but i don't want this, i've already tried that. I wanna change my original background to other i've already make without filling with colors or somethin'

Comment: try
    email.style.backgroundImage="url('image.jpg')";

Comment: It's not changing the currently image. Somehow the css can prevent this change?

Comment: Now it worked, i don't know how, but i've had to upload the image in some website to show it. Thanks for your help Chris.